# how to combine homeUrl with createUrl?

Tags: php, yii

I have an different `homeUrl` and i want it to be used when the `createUrl()` method is being called

e.g

```
Yii::app()->homeUrl = Yii::app()->params['myurl'];
```

but when I do

```
$this->createUrl(Yii::app()->homeUrl.'controller/action');
```

am getting two different url...how to solve this ?

Comment: did you tried `$this->createAbsoluteUrl('controller/action')` ?

Comment: almost the same thing as createUrl...nevermind..i found a solution myself..i'll just string replace or override createUrl

Answer (score 0):

Sasori,

You may need to do the following:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->homeUrl.'?r=controller/action';?>
```

Will output */app/index.php?r=controller/action*